# CrudRepository: findAll() stucks in infinite loop

Tags: mysql, json, spring, hibernate, entity

I have a `OneToMany` data model with two entities. One machine contains many characteristics.

**Problem:** When I try to get the complete data of the data base the program stucks in an infinite loop. See the JSON result - the data is repeated all the time...

```
[{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":[{"name":null,"description":"CHARACTER2","type":0,"value":0,"machine":{"name":"Neue Machine","description":"Description der neuen machine","characteristics":
```

and so on...

I really do not know why that happens. Inserting data programatically seems to **work fine**!
The current data is produced by the following lines of code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/machine", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Collection<Machine> readMachines(){

        Machine machine = new Machine("Neue Machine", "Description der neuen machine");
        //Set<Characteristic> newCharacter =  new HashSet<Characteristic>(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            machine.addCharacteristic(new Characteristic("CHARACTER" + Integer.toString(i),0,0));
        }

        machineRepository.save(machine);

        return (Collection<Machine>) machineRepository.findAll();
    }
```

**Question:** Where does the infinite loop coming from?

**The database model**

**machine:**

[image]

create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `machine` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "characteristic")
public class Characteristic {
    private int characteristic_id; 

    private String name; 

    private String description; 

    private int type; 

    private int value;

    private Machine machine; 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="machine_id")
    public Machine getMachine(){
        return machine;
    }

    public void setMachine(Machine machine){
        this.machine = machine;
    }

    public Characteristic() {}

    public Characteristic(String description, int type, int value) {
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    } 

    public Characteristic(int characteristic_id, String description, int type, int value) {
        this.characteristic_id = characteristic_id;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    } 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="characteristic_id")
    public int getCharacteristic_Id() {
        return characteristic_id;
    }

    public void setCharacteristic_Id(int characteristic_id) {
        this.characteristic_id = characteristic_id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name="type")
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Column(name="value")
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**characteristic:**

[image]

create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `characteristic` (
  `characteristic_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `machine_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`characteristic_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "machine")
public class Machine {
    private int machine_id; 

    private String name;

    private String description; 

    private Set<Characteristic> characteristics;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "machine", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Characteristic> getCharacteristics() {
        return characteristics; 
    }

    public void setCharacteristics(Set<Characteristic> characteristics){
        this.characteristics = characteristics;
    }

    public Machine(){}

    public Machine(String name, String description){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description; 
    }

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return machine_id;
    }

    public void setId(int machine_id) {
        this.machine_id = machine_id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void addCharacteristic(Characteristic characteristic){
        if(this.characteristics == null){
            this.characteristics = new HashSet<Characteristic>();
        }
        characteristic.setMachine(this);
        this.characteristics.add(characteristic);
    }
}
```

CrudRepository:

```
public interface MachineRepository extends CrudRepository<Machine, Integer>{}
```

Comment: Because you have a data with cyclic dependencies.

Comment: @RomanC Thank you for your answer. I understand your point but I do not see the cyclic dependency in my model. Can you explain it more detailed, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you return a collection of `Machine`. This class has *One-To-Many* dependency to `Characteristic`. The `Characteristic` class has *Many-To-One* dependency om `Machine`.

When `Machine` object is serialized it's looking on dependency `Characteristic` the last is looking back on `Machyne`, and so on. These cycle dependencies impossible to serialize until you exclude properties that reference to the same object. You should exclude either *One-To-Many* or *Many-To-One* properties.

Comment: I understand your point. Could you please post a piece of sample code? I am struggling with new errors.. And why do tutorials often suggest such a cyclic dependency?

Comment: This answer is very strong, that's why it has not any code. If you doubt that I cannot write a code you can browse my answers or ask a question that more or less sane.

Comment: I really do no doubt on your skill

Comment: I reward your actions to help you to learn further, you can also upvote this answer because if your application will be able to `@JsonIgnore` properties described in this answer you can forget about cycle dependencies.